# Yaesu FTDX-1200 how to load band stack register

Tags: yaesu, equipment-operation

I have a Yaesu FTDX-1200.  There is a feature that allows storage of 3 sets of frequency for each of the band selection buttons.
I tried pressing store and then the band button but it does not seem to store the current frequency.

How do you program these buttons?

Answer (score 3):

The **Triple Band Stack** will simply remember (store) the last frequency entered or tuned for that band and stack position. Try this:

1. pick a band - 40 meters - by pressing [7.0]
2. Tune to a frequency
3. Press [7.0] again and tune to a different freq on 40 meters
4. Press [7.0] again and tune to yet a different freq on 40 meters

Now, press {7.0} repeatedly and you will cycle through the last 3 tuned (or entered) frequencies on that band. This is the triple band stack — there is no formal store command or button for the triple stack. The [STO] feature is for storing frequencies in Memory/Channel Groups.

The Triple Band Stack will not only store the frequency - it will store mode such as LSB or CW. Both VFO A and B have independent Triple Band Stacks!

I believe this is explained in the manual under “Convenience Features”.